# Flutter: WebView não atualiza a pagina

Tags: flutter, webview

Quando recebo uma mensagem de validação na pagina, não está renderizando na tela, eu preciso realizar um "refrash" manualmente para funcionar.

Antes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu WebViewController:

```
WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
..setNavigationDelegate(
  NavigationDelegate(
    onProgress: (int progress) {},
    onPageStarted: (String url) {},
    onPageFinished: (String url) {},
    onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
    onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
      if (request.url.startsWith('http://www.teste.com.br/login')) {
        return NavigationDecision.prevent;
      }
      return NavigationDecision.navigate;
    },
  ),
)
..loadRequest(Uri.parse('http://www.teste.com.br/login'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri que o fato da minha página não atualizar foi a utilização do `return NavigationDecision.prevent`.

Utilizando somente o `return NavigationDecision.navigate`, todas as validações estão sendo renderizadas na tela.

ficou assim:

```
WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
..setNavigationDelegate(
  NavigationDelegate(
    onProgress: (int progress) {},
    onPageStarted: (String url) {},
    onPageFinished: (String url) {},
    onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
    onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
      return NavigationDecision.navigate;
    },
  ),
)
..loadRequest(Uri.parse('http://www.teste.com.br/login'));
```